# How would I go about joining multiple many-to-one tables in SQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, subquery, backend

So, my problem is I do not know how to go about joining multiple tables, of which some have many-to-one relations. I have the following structure, of which the left one and the right one are linked through eachother with the 'keys' next to their name and the one-to-one or many-to-one relations are described with 1-1 or 1-* depending on which side is many:

```
User <- id  1-1  user_id -> Device
Device <- id  1-*  device_id -> Tracker (has dates)
Tracker <- id  1-*  tracker_id -> Location (has dates)
```

I now want to make an aggregate function with the following: I want to SELECT all from Device, join it with some columns form User (not the problem), join it with only the Tracker-row which has the 'highest date' per Device (so I get the most recent Tracker id + date per device), and from that I want to join Location, of which I want the most recent Location date of the most recent tracker. As you can see: each Device has multiple Trackers, and each Tracker has multiple Locations.

I am able to get the most recent Tracker date for each device, but as soon as I group by tracker_id, I get a list of each Tracker for each device, which I do not want. I currently am using this query to get that result, but do not know how to go on from here:

```
SELECT * FROM public.devices JOIN public.users ON users.id = user_id 
JOIN public.trackers track ON track.device_id = devices.id WHERE track.date = 
SELECT MAX(trackers.date) FROM public.trackers 
WHERE public.trackers.device_id = track.device_id ORDER BY devices.id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

This is verbose but should be easy to follow.

Use `distinct on`, and work from `devices` out:

```
with latest_tracker as (
  select distinct on (device_id) device_id, id as tracker_id, date
    from trackers
   order by devices_id, date desc
), latest_location as (
  select distinct on (t.device_id), t.device_id, l.id, l.date
    from latest_tracker t
         join locations l on l.tracker_id = t.tracker_id
   order by t.device_id, l.date desc
)
select *
  from devices d
       join users u on u.id = d.user_id
       left join latest_location l on l.device_id = d.device_id
```